# programmatically create bookmarks in Gnome

Tags: gnome, gnome3

I would like to automatically create bookmarks for newly created users in Gnome.  Is this possible, and how would I do it?

Comment: what sort of bookmarks? When you do want them to be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=442650

The bookmarks are in that file.

Comment: Cool! its a plain file in ~/.gtk-bookmarks contains one url per line.

Comment: similar to ".hidden" files... I love Gnome for its simplicity!